# parameter passing type in Java

Tags: java, parameters

Codes are below. I just want to know when I call changeName,the parameter passing type in changeName  is value passing or reference passing.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("Mike");
        System.out.println("Before calling changeName:" + student.toString());
        test.changeName(student);
        System.out.println("After calling changeName:" + student.toString());
    }

    public void changeName(Student s){
        s.setName("Alice");
    }
}

class Student{
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: just run it and you will get the answer

Comment: Yes. My mother language is not English, but I've already tried my best to describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is value passing.
In fact, there is no concept of passing by reference in the Java programming language.Don't be misunderstood by C + +.The value passed here is the address of the object.

Comment: Could you please share me a passage about parameter passing type in Java. I want to learn more about it but I can't find a satifactory passage about it now.

Comment: Of course. You can find it in the 《Core Java Volume I》 — Chapter4.This is a great book for abecedarian.